# converting the contents of memory from int to char

Tags: java, virtual-machine

I am working on a virtual operating System as a part of my assignment.The memory is a 2D array of size [300][4].

The problem is when I am printing its contents they are   shown in integer value, even after typecasting it to char still integer values are 
printed.

The problem i am facing is here

```
for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    { 
        System.out.println("M["+i+"]["+j+"]="+M[i][j]);         
    }
}
```

Even after typecasting it shows integer value
Note:The input file contains the following

```
$AMJ001100070003                           
GD10PD10LR10SR40H
$DTA
OPERATING
$END0011
```

So what I do is generate a random memory location for PTR (Page table Register) and then generate another random number for frame and multiply it by 10, for example If the value of frame is 20 ,then `GD10PD10LR10SR40H` is stored at location 200.

So the problem is when I am printing its contents for example memory location 200 its shows 71(value of G),when after typecasting its shows 71 and not 'G'.I also tried adding 48(ASCII value of 0) but no affect.
Kindly help me with this matter.

Where I am doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

This should work, converting the value to a character using the Ascii range of characters:

```
for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            { 
                System.out.println("M["+i+"]["+j+"]="+(char)M[i][j]);         
            }
        }
```